# function call std::vector

Tags: c++

Below is how i am calling the function Xpath.evaluate. This is not working because of the wrong function call. please help

```
std::vector<std::string> album;

xpath.evaluate("*[local-name()=*album*]/text()",album);
```

the xpath.evaluate function is

```
void XPath::evaluate(char const* xpath, vector<string>& result) const
throw (Error) {
    result.clear();

    vector<xmlNodePtr> r;
    evaluate(xpath, r);

    xmlBufferPtr buff = xmlBufferCreate();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < r.size(); ++i) {
        xmlSaveCtxtPtr ctxt = xmlSaveToBuffer(buff, "UTF-8",
                                              XML_SAVE_NO_DECL | XML_SAVE_NO_XHTML);
        xmlNodePtr clone = xmlCopyNode(r[i], 1);
        xmlSaveTree(ctxt, clone);

        // OMG
        if (clone->doc != NULL && clone->doc != r[i]->doc) {
            xmlFreeDoc(clone->doc);
        }
        else {
            xmlFreeNode(clone);
        }

        xmlSaveFlush(ctxt);
        result.push_back(string((char const*) buff->content, buff->use));
        xmlSaveClose(ctxt);
        xmlBufferEmpty(buff);
    }
    xmlBufferFree(buff);
}
```

how do I call this function ??

Comment: `xpath.evaluate("*[local-name()=*album*]/text()",album);`

Comment: Sorry it was a mistake from copying. But even with out it it doesnot work

Comment: Doesn't work in what way? What's the error you're seeing?

Comment: the error was how i print it.

Comment: What does that actually mean?

Comment: I tried to print in a normal statement like printf for album . now im using a for loop and trying to get the list of albums

Comment: How do you know it is not working "because of the wrong function call?"

Comment: yes thank you i figured out that i was calling a wrong function call.

Answer (score 0):

`album[2]` is a `std::string`. You only need to pass `album` to match the `vector<string>&` argument.